# texstudio macro for inline math

Tags: latex

I have a few macros in TexStudio that work more or less as expected except for one that gives me some problems. I have it setup such that when I press `mm` it inserts inline math `$|$` and places the cursor beterrn the `$` signs. All is well unless I need to write a word like `communications` because as I write it I get `co$unications$`. This is because the macro triggers and I have no idea how to make it to only trigger if the cursor is next to a space character because I don't know many words in the English language that start with `mm`.

So the question is: how to I trigger the macro only if the cursor is next to a  character?

Cheers

Comment: Ok this is a classic RTFM moment! I will answer my own question: the macro trigger should be: ``(?<=\ )mm``. This works great! Should I remove the question? Or should I add an answer maybe it will be useful for others?

Comment: Add an answer, if the community thinks that it is not helpful for other users it will vote for closing/deleting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic RTFM moment! In order to achieve the result of the macro correctly (i.e. trigger it only next to a space character) the macro should be

```
(?<=\ )mm
```

The macro settings are as follows:
[image]